# Another javascript array challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Solving another array manipulation, and I'm taking longer than usual to solve this. I need help in combining array values:

```
var array1 = ["alpha|LJ", "bravo|MH", "charlie|MH", "delta|MF",
              "echo|16", "{foxtrot}|GG", "{golf}|HS"];

var array2 = ["charlie-{golf}-{foxtrot}", "echo-{golf}"]; //some templates
```

such that the final array be:

```
final_array = ["alpha-LJ", "bravo-MH", "charlie-HS-GG-MH", "delta-MF",
               "echo-HS-16"];
```

To make it clear how I arrived with the final_array, alpha, bravo and delta only got their "|" replaced with "-" since they are not found on my array2 template.  charlie and echo got the template so the respective values of the {} were replaced based on array1.  Array1 honestly is not the best key:value relationship that I could come up for now.

Here are some requirementL:

```
* Anything in array1 with {} braces are not meant to be templated.
* Keywords in array2 will always have a matching value in array1.
```

I've read about jquery .map() and thinking that it is achievable using this, maybe together with Regexp.  Hope you'll utilize these. Also, if it helps, final_array can be of any order.

I really need to up my knowledge on these two topics... :|

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have any control over the structure of array1, try using json, that structure is just... mad...  With json you could at least have a key-value lookup without having to break up strings and use overly complicated regexes. To me, you're designing for a slow script.  Also a relevant quote: "Some developers, when presented with a problem think, I know, I'll use a regex. Now they have 2 problems"

Comment: Thank you for including your input and desired output. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the relationship. Why does `alpha|LJ` get a hyphen? Why does `bravo|MH` keep the `MH`, but `charlie|MH` has it replaced with something else? Perhaps I'm daft, but I can't see the logic being applied.

Comment: hehe the quote is just funny! :) I'll see what I can do with the first array

Comment: @Phrogz, bravo retained the MH because its not found on the template. If it is not found on the template, just replace the | text with hypen. the charlie was replaced with something else because of the template below (array2)

Comment: Is it ever possible for a template to use the same value twice, e.g. `"charlie-{golf}-{foxtrot}-{golf}"`?

Comment: @Phrogz, no :) {xxx} are usable only once per template

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? The format of these data structures is obscene....It sounds like you need to back up some.

Comment: This should just be deleted, nobody will ever have *this* question again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This managed to get your desired output, though I made a few assumptions:

- Anything in array1 with {} braces are not meant to be templated.
- Keywords in array2 will always have a matching value in array1 (this can easily be changed, but not sure what your rule would be).

Code:

```
// This is the main code
var final_array = $.map(array1, function (item) {
    var components = item.split('|');
    // Ignore elements between {} braces
    if (/^\{.*\}$/.test(components[0])) return;
    components[0] = template(components[0]); 
    return components.join('-');
});

// Helper to lookup array2 for a particular string and template it
// with the values from array1
function template(str) {
    var index = indexOfMatching(array2, str, '-');
    if (index == -1) return str;

    var components = array2[index].split('-');
    var result = [str];
    for (var i = 1; i < components.length; i++) {
        result.push(array1[indexOfMatching(array1, components[i], '|')]
            .split('|')[1]);
    }
    return result.join('-');
}

// Helper to for looking up array1 and array2
function indexOfMatching(array, target, separator) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].split(separator)[0] === target) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this, let me know which part is not clear so that I could edit my question. thanks!

Comment: @Marvzz I added my assumptions

Comment: you got all the assumption correct.  I thought it was quite obvious. I edited my question.

Comment: Hi box9 sorry, seems im having issues with this, i get template is not a function error on firebug, Am I missing something?

Comment: @Marvzz, hmm Firebug seems to be doing something odd here. It doesn't parse `function` declarations out-of-order as the browser normally would. For firebug, put the `var final_array = $.map` part *after* the two helper functions. This shouldn't be a problem on a regular page though.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Updated to match your output and comment some of the madness. This doesn't feel like it's the most efficient, given the `split()` done to values at the start and then again at the end...but it works.

```
function funkyTransform( values, templates ){
  // Make a copy of the array we were given so we can mutate it
  // without rudely changing something passed to our function.
  var result = values.concat();

  // Map {value} entries for later lookup, and throw them out of the result
  var valueMap = {};
  for (var i=result.length-1;i>=0;--i){
    var pair = result[i].split('|');
    if (pair[0][0]=="{"){
      valueMap[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      result.splice(i,1); // Yank this from the result
    }
  }
  console.log(valueMap);
  // {
  //   "{foxtrot}": "GG",
  //   "{golf}":    "HS"
  // }

  // Use the value map to replace text in our "templates", and
  // create a map from the first part of the template to the rest.
  // THIS SHOULD REALLY SCAN THE TEMPLATE FOR "{...}" PIECES
  // AND LOOK THEM UP IN THE MAP; OOPS O(N^2)
  var templateMap = {};
  for (var i=templates.length-1;i>=0;--i){
    var template = templates[i];
    for (var name in valueMap){
      if (valueMap.hasOwnProperty(name)){
        template = template.replace(name,valueMap[name]);
      }
    }
    var templateName = template.split('-')[0];
    templateMap[ templateName ] = template.slice(templateName.length+1);
  }
  console.log(templateMap);
  // {
  //   "charlie": "HS-GG",
  //   "echo":    "HS"
  // }

  // Go through the results again, replacing template text from the templateMap
  for (var i=result.length-1;i>=0;--i){
    var pieces = result[i].split('|');
    var template = templateMap[pieces[0]];
    if (template) pieces.splice(1,0,template);
    result[i] = pieces.join('-');
  }
  return result;
}

var output = funkyTransform( array1, array2 );
console.log(output);
// ["alpha-LJ", "bravo-MH", "charlie-HS-GG-MH", "delta-MF", "echo-HS-16"]
```

Comment: thanks for this, somewhat useful, yeah this helped move me a bit.

Comment: I've updated the answer to one that works, and now I'm sadly going to vote to close this question as not useful to anyone but you.

Comment: Ok i got no prob with that, Thanks for your help too. :)